# Gmail History API list method does not send the full data associated with the message

Tags: gmail-api

When calling the list method of the history module, the expected response as per the documentation is:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "id": unsigned long,
      "messages": [
        users.messages Resource
      ],
      "messagesAdded": [
        {
          "message": users.messages Resource
        }
      ],
      "messagesDeleted": [
        {
          "message": users.messages Resource
        }
      ],
      "labelsAdded": [
        {
          "message": users.messages Resource,
          "labelIds": [
            string
          ]
        }
      ],
      "labelsRemoved": [
        {
          "message": users.messages Resource,
          "labelIds": [
            string
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long
}
```

The "users.messages Resource" should contain:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "internalDate": long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}
```

However, in the response I get, pasted below, *the messages Resource does not have the complete data* ( trimmed the response to highlight the part which does not match the expected output )

```
 "messagesAdded": [
    {
     "message": {
      "id": "15ccf31acc315dc5",
      "threadId": "15ccf31acc315dc5",
      "labelIds": [
       "UNREAD",
       "CATEGORY_UPDATES",
       "INBOX"
      ]
     }
    }
   ]
```

Are there any parameters that I need to pass in when retrieving the data?

Note: Here is the link to the Issue Tracker:
*https://issuetracker.google.com/63548371 History API list method does not send the full data associated with the message*

Comment: Have you tried specifying in the fields property the value you're trying to request? You can see that in [the Try-it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get), there's a fields parameter where you can specify properties you want returned.

Comment: AFAIK, the _field_ param acts like a selector. If nothing is passed the API returns the full data. However, I did try passing in the required params. API returns the same data.

Note: The issue is with the response in history API's message resource part. The message resource does not have the full data.